# (BASH) String to execute is formed correctly, but evaluated with errors

Tags: bash, command-line, cygwin, aws

I have been persistently trying to solve an issue with some code that I'd like to use to interact with AWS CLI. After trying for about a week, I decided to try to create the string of the command I'd like to execute and use `eval` on the string (I know this is not recommended, but I was running out of ideas...). Even this seems to not be working.

With `echo` my command prints fine, but it is giving me a "command not found error" when trying to evaluate. I noticed that if I copy/paste this sample line into my Cygwin terminal:

```
aws s3 cp s3://a-bucket/users/3e8c95b4-c5ee-4edc-954e-6d988d30557e/7EF70C5F-B8D6-4E21-B495-E91963CE1BDD-RIGHT.zip 'c:/users/basud/desktop/testerData' --recursive
```

I get this in my terminal before I even press enter:

```
--recursive4E21-B495-E91963CE1BDD-RIGHT.zip 'c:/users/basud/desktop/testerData'
```

Could this be an error with Windows carriage return?

Comment: (Referring to the second half of your post....) Is the command longer than one line of your terminal can fit? Because it kind of looks like line wrapping is occurring but without scrolling up a line / line feed. If this is the case next question is "are you using any kind of fancy prompt (PS1)?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with AWS CLI but with cygwin. In cygwin shell you access your C:\ drive with `/cygdrive/c/` thus you should try `cp` to

```
/cygdrive/c/users/basud/desktop/testerData
```